# STM32F4 - USART - Receive data array - reads only first frame

Tags: interrupt-handling, transmission, usart

today I'm fighting with controlling my uC from the PC.
On a button click, I'm sending data to uC which is to change some values in the program. **First of all**, the problem is that my program reads only first frame received. **Secondly**, my program gets stuck when I reinitialize PDM_Filter Structure

What is important - Rx buffer of USART is 16-bit.

**Data format is like** 6x byte (uint8) that are:

0) ASCII symbol - ! or # or & - symbol indicates what happens next;
1) mic_gain; 2)3) HP Filter cutoff freq; 4)5) LP Filter cutoff freq

So I am receiving 3 x uint16

**How it looks like on uC code:**

```
union
{
    uint16_t szes[3];
    uint8_t os[6];
}RxBuffer;
```

Interrupt Handler - I had cut the part that works just fine.

```
void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{   

    if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) == SET)
    {       

        j=0;
        while (j<3)
        {       
            RxBuffer.szes[j] = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);           
            j++;
        }           

        if(RxBuffer.os[0] == 39)
        {
            DoFlag = false;
            I2S_Cmd(SPI2, DISABLE);     

            //_PDM(sampling_frequency, RxBuffer.szes[2], RxBuffer.szes[1]);     

            Filter.HP_HZ = RxBuffer.szes[1];
            Filter.LP_HZ = RxBuffer.szes[2];
            PDM_Filter_Init(&Filter);
            GPIO_SetBits(GPIOD, LED_Blue);
            mic_gain = RxBuffer.os[1];      
            Delay(1000);
            GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOD, LED_Blue);        
            I2S_Cmd(SPI2, ENABLE);          
            DoFlag = true;
        }

         USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
    }
}
```

How intialization of **PDM_Filter** structure (from `libPDMFilter_Keil.lib`) looks for me:

```
  Filter.Fs = frequency_s;
  Filter.HP_HZ = high_pass_cutoff;
  Filter.LP_HZ = low_pass_cutoff;
  Filter.In_MicChannels = 1;
  Filter.Out_MicChannels = 1;
  PDM_Filter_Init(&Filter);
```

I'm trying to change cutoff frequencies - in order to do so, I reinitialize structure.

Comment: Have you initialized the CRC clock? From [here](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/ca/18/be/bb/f8/53/47/a5/DM00040808.pdf/files/DM00040808.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00040808.pdf) "Before calling the PDM_Filter_Init() function, the application code must enable the clock of the STM32 microcontroller CRC peripheral (configuration done in RCC register). Otherwise, the PDM_Filter_Init() function will fail and go into an infinite loop."

Comment: @Gusman
Yup, for the 1st time I'm initializing in other function

`void _PDM(uint32_t frequency_s, uint16_t low_pass_cutoff, uint16_t high_pass_cutoff)
{ 
 
 RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_CRC, ENABLE); // zegar CRC dla struktury filtru PDM
 
 // Initialize PDM filter
  Filter.Fs = frequency_s;
  Filter.HP_HZ = high_pass_cutoff;
  Filter.LP_HZ = low_pass_cutoff;
  Filter.In_MicChannels = 1;
  Filter.Out_MicChannels = 1;
  PDM_Filter_Init(&Filter);
}`